# Setting UUID field to NULL with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm having a database table which contains a `assigned_id` field which has the type `uuid`.

The database is postgres and my ORM is gorm. I was wondering how its possible to set that `assigned_id` to `NULL`?

I've tried setting the field to nil in the model, as well as using `gorm.Expr("NULL")`, `nil` or `sql.NullString`.
None of those methods work.

Maybe someone will be able to answer that question for me.

Comment: Would  `gorm:"default:NULL"` work (as in [issue 5882](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5882))

Comment: The issue is that I don't want to set it as a default. Since you can assign someone to an issue, you should also be able to un-assign someone. The issue with that is that I would normally express that through a NULL value. An ugly solution would be to update it with a nullUUID

Answer (score 4):

So you can declare a custom type to handle uuid (or any other non-default type). I've provided the implementation and it works for me with examples. NOTE: I've already declared a custom type to handle null string but I've left it out for brevity.

Also I did not do a complete test coverage of this code, so please take it as a starting point.

```
type NullUUID struct {
    UUID  uuid.UUID
    Valid bool
}

func (nd *NullUUID) Scan(value interface{}) (err error) {
    var s uuid.UUID
    if err := s.Scan(value); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // if nil then make Valid false
    if reflect.TypeOf(value) == nil {
        *nd = NullUUID{Valid: false}
    } else {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *nd = NullUUID{s, true}
    }

    return nil
}

func (nd NullUUID) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if !nd.Valid {
        return nil, nil
    }

    return nd.Value, nil
}

func (nd NullUUID) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !nd.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }

    return json.Marshal(nd.UUID.String())
}

func (nd *NullUUID) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var str string

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &str)
    if err != nil {
        nd.Valid = false
        return err
    }

    id, err := uuid.Parse(str)
    if err != nil {
        nd.Valid = false
        return err
    }

    nd.UUID = id
    nd.Valid = true
    return err
}
```

This also handles marshalling and unmarshalling so it either prints the value or "null", but you can edit this is required.

Here is my tested example:

```
 id | text 
----+------
    | sda

// Row result:
main.Row{Id:main.NullUUID{UUID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, Valid:false}, Text:main.NullString{String:"sda", Valid:true}}

// Row marshalled:
{"id":null,"text":"sda"}

// Row unmarshalled:
main.Row{Id:main.NullUUID{UUID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, Valid:false}, Text:main.NullString{String:"", Valid:false}} // seems to be a bug in my null string unmarshalling but I don't think it's relevant here
```

Just in case, I also tested non null uuid and here is the result:

```
// Row marshalled
{"id":"889f2163-ee59-4632-b238-3ac9574f111e","text":null}

// Row unmarshalled
main.Row{Id:main.NullUUID{UUID:uuid.UUID{0x88, 0x9f, 0x21, 0x63, 0xee, 0x59, 0x46, 0x32, 0xb2, 0x38, 0x3a, 0xc9, 0x57, 0x4f, 0x11, 0x1e}, Valid:true}, Text:main.NullString{String:"", Valid:true}} // again seems to be a bug in my null string unmarshalling but I don't think it's relevant here

// Printed UUID string
889f2163-ee59-4632-b238-3ac9574f111e
```